# Is a multiselect (with a few exposed options) always better than a drop down menu?

Tags: forms, dropdown, multi-selection, combobox

Consider the two inputs below:

[image: Screenshot showing a drop down menu and a multiselect input]

Ignoring the poor label placement for a moment...

It seems to me that in many cases, either of these inputs could perform the same function.

**Do either of these inputs have a big advantage over the other in terms of form usability?**

I have read (e.g. [Label Placement in Forms :: UXmatters](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php)) that drop down menus have a significant impact on saccade times.

Is it possible that a multiselect (even constrained to a single selection) might be a better option?

**Each has its own prima facie advantages:**

- The multiselect allows the user to immediately see a sample of the options available, which may aid in quickly understanding the intent of the input (and clarify an ambiguous label)
- The drop down menu allows shows the selected option as its current state, and so allows a user to quickly verify their selection, in a way that the multiselect does not

**Finally, has there been any discussion of a combination of the two?**

The wireframe combo I've mocked up below shares the visibility of the multiselect options with the statefulness of the drop down menu.

[image]

Are there any obvious problems with this alternative?

Note: I realise this alternative is very close to a [combo-box](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combobox), with one significant difference. Here, the user does not need to start typing to reveal available options. It seems to me the combo-box is great for allowing the user to actively narrow a long list in an efficient way. But combo-boxes do not generally create the visibility of options that a multiselect does.

Note: I'd use "multiselect" and "list-box" as synonyms.

Comment: Hey Justin. I'm a little confused. Are you suggesting the multi-select could be a way to go, even though the user can only choose one option? Cheers, Jessica

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with multi-selects.

- they are uncommon, therefore potentially confusing for users
- they require the use of a modifier key, again potentially confusing/difficult for users
- no native default implementation for mobile devices

I'd consider a common implementation that you do see on mobile, which I think works well in desktop situations and that's a scrollable checkbox list.

It's clearly a list, so you can see the options immediately, and the checkboxes make it clear that you can select more than one without the need for any sort of modifier key.

Comment: You misunderstand the question - He is referring to the look of the multiselect, not the fact that you *can* multi-select.

Comment: They go hand in hand.